# connect to the database twice faster or connect once and store it locally?

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, logic

I have a question in logic, to be honest I can't categorize it. 
My question is
If I have a table in database with 2 columns let's say table called articles with article title and article content.  and I develop mobile app which displays all the title in a list then when the user clicked on the title the will move to a new page "activity" and display its content.
I have 2 ways to develop that.

1- connect to the database once, select all the titles and all the content and store it locally and just display the content when its title is clicked

2- connect to the database twice. once to select all the titles, another one to select its content when clicked without storing anything locally

Please notice it is a mobile app so it doesn't have a huge space to store locally.

My main question. which one of this method will be faster and efficient?

Comment: Number 2 is the obvious choice, simply because the **content** can be much much larger than the **title**. So downloading massive amounts of **content** that the user doesn't want is a huge waste of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 seems better, because :

- you mentioned that you don’t have a lot of local space available
- only the content that the user needs will be retrieved, which, depending on the total size of the content, could save a lot of space AND time

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 seems a better option as already explained. To add, even while going with option 2, one of the way to further improve performance can be to use caching mechanisms for the retrieved title and content so that the database is not called every time for the same data for subsequent requests.

For example, 
Request 1: title 1 is requested. Database is called and content 1 is returned from db. Content 1 is delivered to the user and cached.
Request n: title 1 is requested again, content 1 is retrieved from cache and returned to the user.